# Tricky Indefinite Integral

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$\int \frac{(x^2 + x)}{(e^x + x + 1)^2}dx$

I was thinking along the lines of breaking the numerator into denominator differentiation and generic function with help of division rule.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Divide the numerator & denominator by $e^{2x}$

$$\dfrac{x^2+x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}=\dfrac{xe^{-x}\cdot(x+1)e^{-x}}{\{1+e^{-x}(x+1)\}^2}$$

Set $1+e^{-x}(x+1)=u$

Comment: ok, granted, is there a better {more general} way to reach it, suppose coefficients were not as simple as all 1's, is there a general way to approach these type of questions where e^x and polynomials are mixed?

Comment: @ELiT generally no, for example, there is no closed form for the integral $\int \frac{e^x}{x}dx$

Comment: I'm talking about exactly the same type of questions with just different coefficients , given that it is solvable and also quite easy with one or two step problem like the problem given above, How should we go about breaking the numerator {and then finding values like we do in partial fractions} or is there a better method?